# Can you unblock boost::asio::io_context while waiting for async_read?

Tags: c++, websocket, boost-asio, boost-beast

im trying to connect to a server via boost asio and beast. I need to send heartbeats to the server every 40 seconds, but when I try to, my write requests get stuck in a queue and never get executed, unless the server sends something first.

I have this code to look for new messages that come in.

```
this->ioContext.run();

thread heartbeatThread(&client::heartbeatCycle, this);

while (this->p->is_socket_open()) {
    this->ioContext.restart();
    this->p->asyncQueue("", true);
    this->ioContext.run();
}
```

The `asyncQueue` function just calls async_read, and blocks the io context. The `heartbeatCycle` tries to send heartbeats, but gets stuck in the queue. If I force it to send anyways, I get

`Assertion failed: (id_ != T::id), function try_lock, file soft_mutex.hpp, line 89.`

When the server sends a message, the queue is unblocked, and all the queued messages go through, until there is no more work, and the io_context starts blocking again.

So my main question is, is there any way to unblock the io context without having the server send a message? If not, is there a way to emulate the server sending a message?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I have this queue function that queues messages being sent called asyncQueue.

```
void session::asyncQueue(const string& payload, const bool& madeAfterLoop)
{
    if(!payload.empty())
    {
        queue_.emplace_back(payload);
    }

    if(payload.empty() && madeAfterLoop)
    {
        queue_.emplace_back("KEEPALIVE");
    }

    // If there is something to write, write it.
    if(!currentlyQueued_ && !queue_.empty() && queue_.at(0) != "KEEPALIVE")
    {
        currentlyQueued_ = true;
        ws_.async_write(
                net::buffer(queue_.at(0)),
                beast::bind_front_handler(
                        &session::on_write,
                        shared_from_this()));
        queue_.erase(queue_.begin());
    }

    // If there is nothing to write, read the buffer to keep stream alive
    if(!currentlyQueued_ && !queue_.empty())
    {
        currentlyQueued_ = true;
        ws_.async_read(
                buffer_,
                beast::bind_front_handler(
                        &session::on_read,
                        shared_from_this()));
        queue_.erase(queue_.begin());
    }
}
```

The problem is when the code has nothing no work left to do, it calls async read, and gets stuck until the server sends something.

In the function where I initialized the io_context, I also created a separate thread to send heartbeats every x seconds.

```
void client::heartbeatCycle()
{
    while(this->p->is_socket_open())
    {
        this->p->asyncQueue(bot::websocket::sendEvents::getHeartbeatEvent(cache_), true );
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10000));
    }
}
```

Lastly, I have these 2 lines in my on_read function that runs whenever async read is called.

```
currentlyQueued_ = false;
asyncQueue();
```

Once there is no more work to do, the program calls `async_read` but `currentlyQueued_` is never set to false.

The problem is the io_context is stuck looking for something to read. What can I do to stop the io_context from blocking the heartbeats from sending?

The only thing I have found that stops the io_context from blocking is when the server sends me a message. When it does, `currentlyQueued_` is set to false, and the queue able to run and the queue is cleared.

That is the reason im looking for something that can emulate the server sending me a message. So is there a function that can do that in asio/beast? Or am I going about this the wrong way.
Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: You say "I have this code to look for new messages that come in" but none of that code apparently even reads. Please make your code minimal and self-contained, so we can see what you need.

Comment: Oh, ok. I updated the message to give details and clarify what is wrong with the program. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Oof. There's still so much we can't tell. What is the type of `queue_` exactly? Right now it seems very very [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) to `erase` from it immediately after initiating the `async_write` on `queue_.at(0)`. The many bespoke state variables, both locally, member *and* even passed as argument seem a recipe for confusion. Are you looking for a [simpler outgoing queue pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a85371%20%5bboost-asio%5d%20outbox_%20)?

Comment: Note that in principle full-duplex means that both 1 `async_read` and 1 `async_write` can be in flight at the same time (for the same IO object). It looks a bit as if you are trying to conditionally schedule a read. The usual pattern is to *always* have a read pending, and initiate write as soon as _the first_ outgoing message is enqueued. [Optionally, have timers to enqueue heartbeats or cancel on idle timeout; All of these without any need for extra threads]

Comment: Hmm, I think i need to redo the queue! If I try to `async_write` while an async_read is pending I get the error `Assertion failed: (id_ != T::id), function try_lock, file soft_mutex.hpp, line 89.`. My write function calls `async_read` right after writing. Could it be giving this error because as soon as I run the function to write , it tries to read twice?

Comment: omg that was it!!! Thanks sooo much!! i had no idea that websockets were full-duplex, that makes so much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to run the io_service elsewhere (on a thread, or in main, after starting an async chain).

Right now you're calling `restart()` on it which simply doesn't afford continuous operation. Why `stop()` or let it run out of work at all?

Note, manually starting threads [is atypical](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html) and [unsafe](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__websocket__stream.html#beast.ref.boost__beast__websocket__stream.thread_safety:%7E:text=Unsafe.%20The%20application%20must%20also%20ensure%20that%20all%20asynchronous%20operations%20are%20performed%20within%20the%20same%20implicit%20or%20explicit%20strand.).

I would give examples, but [lots](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/examples.html) already exist (also on this site). I'd need to see question code with more detail to give concrete suggestions.

Comment: I tried to let it never run out of work by calling `ws_.async_read` when there was nothing else to read, but I got the same result of the program waiting for something to read before doing anything else. I updated my post to give specific details about what the problem is. Thanks for the help!